# Erro ao carregar média de uma coluna

Tags: r

1. Troquei o valor de NA por zero, transformando em character porque não conseguia calcular a média.
2. Ao tentar calcular a média novamente aparecia o seguinte erro:

> ```
> Warning message:
>   In mean.default(x = "ECONOMIA INSTITUCIONALISTA") :
> argumento não é numérico nem lógico: retornando NA
> ```

Comment: Por favor, leiam a resposta aceite neste Meta [Downvoting of new user questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3515/downvoting-of-new-user-questions/3524)

Comment: 1) Não é preciso trocar o valor de `NA` por zero, muito menos transformar em `character`. 2) O erro diz que `"ECONOMIA INSTITUCIONALISTA"` não é um número ou `FALSE/TRUE`, como é que quer calcular a média disso?!? 3) Ponha a saída de `dput(dados)` na pergunta ou se `dados` for muito grande, de `dput(head(dados, 20))`.

Answer (score 2):

```
# para que os resultados sejam reproduzíveis
set.seed(42)

# gerar os dados
x <- rnorm(10)
x
# [1]  1.37095845 -0.56469817  0.36312841  0.63286260  0.40426832 -0.10612452
# [7]  1.51152200 -0.09465904  2.01842371 -0.06271410

# adicionando NA's para exemplo
x[c(3, 5, 8)] <- NA
x
# [1]  1.3709584 -0.5646982         NA  0.6328626         NA -0.1061245
# [7]  1.5115220         NA  2.0184237 -0.0627141
```

Utilizando somente a função `mean()` ele reconhece a presença de `NA` no vetor e então retorna um `NA`:

```
mean(x)
# [1] NA
```

**Importante**: considerar o `NA` como zero (0) ou `NA` vai mudar o resultado. É importante que você saiba isto para então escolher o método mais apropriado para os seus objetivos.

```
# média considerando NA
mean(x, na.rm = T)
# [1] 0.6857471

# média considerando NA como zero
x[which(is.na(x))] <- 0
mean(x)
# [1] 0.480023
```